# Getting import error in installed package - h5py

Tags: python, importerror, h5py

Getting the import error for h5py but I already installed that. But it was working in python shell.

```
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import os
import h5py


if not os.path.isfile('datasets/mini.h5'):
    print("Downloading Conceptnet Numberbatch word embeddings...")
    conceptnet_url = 'http://conceptnet.s3.amazonaws.com/precomputed- 
    data/2016/numberbatch/17.06/mini.h5'
    urlretrieve(conceptnet_url, 'datasets/mini.h5')


with h5py.File('datasets/mini.h5', 'r') as f:
    all_words = [word.decode('utf-8') for word in f['mat']['axis1'][:]]
    all_embeddings = f['mat']['block0_values'][:]
```

The error I am getting :

```
import h5py
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _errors: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: You mention the import was working in the Python shell. Where are you getting this error then?

Comment: I was getting problem in my program!

Comment: It was the conda environment

Comment: Sounds like you are running in 2 different enviornemnts (and only one has h5py package installed). Please clarify what you mean by "it was working in Python shell". Are you referring to the Conda environment command window? Have you tried to `import h5py` in the spyder IDE IPython console?

Comment: I was using conda environment. Yes I'm referring to conda command window.